# What is modified Garwick's Algorithm exactly?

Tags: algorithm, stack

Garwick's Algorithm is an algorithm for dealing with stack overflows. I know the what the original algorithm is and how it works. However, there is a modified Garwick's algorithm and I have a very vague description of it "even stacks growing in the left direction, and odd stacks in the right direction".

The illustration of the modified algorithm from my lecture note is as the following, which is also very vague.

> [image]

Can anyone help give more details about this modified algorithm, or provide some reference? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to put 2 stacks in an array, then you can put start one stack at the start of the array, growing upward as you push on elements, and one stack at the end, growing downward.

This way you don't need to worry about redistributing free space when one of them fills up, because they both use the *same* free space, and you can freely push onto *either* stack until the whole array is full.

The modified Garwick algorithm you refer to extends this idea to more than 2 stacks.  With the original Garwick algorithm, the array is divided into N segments, and each segment has one stack, with all stacks growing in the same direction.   In the modified version, the array is divided into N/2 segments, and each segment has *2* stacks, one growing upward from the start of the segment, and one growing downward from the end.

In the modified algorithm, when one segment fills up, free space is redistributed among segments (pairs of stacks) in the same way that the original algorithm redistributes space among single stacks.